# How to execute Android verified boot during first boot after updating OS in Android?

Tags: android, kernel, boot, trusted-boot

I need to execute AVB (Android verified boot) during first boot after updating Android OS. `BOARD_AVB_ENABLE = true` is already present in the mk file `device/hikey/common/BoardConfigCommon.mk` in the external/AVB folder.

I want to know how to check if it is detected normally or not.

Comment: This looks like a question for [android.se]

Comment: @nobody off-topic if this is related to ROM development/modification.

Comment: AVB always runs on boot automatically.